# Python function looping through a dictionary of sets removing and adding items updating only some items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, set

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I have two dictionaries:  **parent_dict** has a series of sets as values &  **pub_plat_dict** is a look-up dictionary that seeks to correct the names of the items that make up the sets in **parent_dict**.

The function **update_dict** allows names where it finds a '.' to *pass*.  If it doesn't find a name then it will *try* to find the name in the **pub_plat_dict**. If found it will *.remove* the old name and *.add* the updated name. If the name isn't present, then I want the program to move to the next item.

When I run the function **update_dict** corrects the first item in the **parent_dict**, accurately skips multiple items that don't need to be updated but then doesn't *.remove* or *.add* the other wrongly named items.

**Sample Data**

```
parent_dict = {
    '49d238407e0102ba':{'opportunity_history'}
    , 'f9d53c74ec1d2ff6':{'servicer.trial_balance','src_platform.loan','src_platform.loan_disbursement'}
    , 'fc35a98e0cfaab3d':{'loan', 'loan_agreement', 'opportunity_compliance_flag','zodiac'}
}

pub_plat_dict = {'loan':'src_platform.loan',
              'opportunity_compliance_flag':'src_platform.opportunity_compliance_flag',
              'opportunity_history':'src_platform.opportunity_history',
              'loan_agreement': 'src_platform_mosaic_live.loan_agreement'}
```

**Function**

```
def update_dict(parent_dict):
    for tbls in parent_dict.values():
        for tbl in tbls:
            if tbl.find(".") != -1:
                pass
            else:
                try:
                    update = pub_plat_dict[tbl]
                    tbls.remove(tbl)
                    tbls.add(update)
                except:
                    pass
            return(parent_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'49d238407e0102ba': {'src_platform.opportunity_history'}, 'f9d53c74ec1d2ff6': {'src_platform.loan', 'src_platform.loan_disbursement', 'servicer.trial_balance'}, 'fc35a98e0cfaab3d': {'opportunity_compliance_flag', 'loan_agreement', 'loan', 'zodiac'}}
```

**NOTE:** the first item is updated correctly but everything else is left unchanged.

I did the following loop to try to figure out my error (keeping it as close to the **update_dict** code as I could).

```
for tbls in parent_dict.values():
    for tbl in tbls:
        if tbl.find('.') != -1:
            print("UNCHANGED-" + tbl)
        else:
            try:
                print("CHANGED-" + pub_plat_dict[tbl])
            except:
                print("FAILURE-"+ tbl)
```

It gives me the following output:

```
UNCHANGED-src_platform.opportunity_history
UNCHANGED-src_platform.loan
UNCHANGED-src_platform.loan_disbursement
UNCHANGED-servicer.trial_balance
CHANGED-src_platform.opportunity_compliance_flag
CHANGED-src_platform_mosaic_live.loan_agreement
CHANGED-src_platform.loan
FAILURE-zodiac
```

Aside from the capitalized- word this is what I would expect the parent_dict would now look like. So my *.remove* and *.add* aren't working consistently.

EDIT: I also substituted *.discard* for *.remove*, the output did not change.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the function to work as I created it.  Part of the issue is where the `return` statement appears. Using a `return` inside of a loop will break it and exit the function even if the iteration is still not finished. Another issue might be the redundant logic in the function.

I decided to create a new dictionary and use a list as the dict's values instead of sets. I simplified the logic in the function and got rid of the `if` statement which seemed redundant in light of the `try` clause.

```
from collections import defaultdict

cln_parent_dict = defaultdict(list)

def update_dict(parent_dict):
    for key in parent_dict:
        for value in parent_dict[key]:
            try:
                cln_parent_dict[key].append(pub_plat_dict[value])
            except:
                cln_parent_dict[key].append(value)    
    return(cln_parent_dict)
```

when I run the function I get what I expect:

**Function Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'49d238407e0102ba': ['src_platform.opportunity_history'], 'f9d53c74ec1d2ff6': ['servicer.trial_balance', 'src_platform.loan_disbursement', 'src_platform.loan'], 'fc35a98e0cfaab3d': ['zodiac', 'src_platform_mosaic_live.loan_agreement', 'src_platform.opportunity_compliance_flag', 'src_platform.loan']})
```

Overall the change seems to work for the 100K items in the dataset.

Thanks to everyone for taking a look.